# Calling a Stored Procedure in Access 2007 from VB 6.0

Tags: stored-procedures, vb6, ms-access-2007, adodb

I need to call a stored procedure that was created in Access 2007 from the program in VB 6.0.

This is the working Stored Procedure on the Access db when you right click -> Design View:

```
PARAMETERS prodCode Text ( 255 ), orderNum Text ( 255 );
SELECT Sum(FullPrice) AS Expr1
FROM Transacs
WHERE (((Transacs.prodcode)=[prodCode]) AND ((Transacs.ordernum)=[orderNum]) AND ((Transacs.Type)='R'));
```

This is the code that needs fixing in VB 6.0:

```
Set TransRs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim transcommQuery As String
transcommQuery = "execute SP_SumOfTransComm " & prodcode & " " & orderNum

TransRs.Open transcommQuery, db, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
```

Line 3: **transcommQuery = "execute SP_SumOfTransComm " & selProdcode & " " & selPolNo** is the one I need fixing. How to correctly call the Stored Procedure from there?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Command objects to call stored procedures. For detailed information you can take a look [here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/using-ado-and-stored-procedures-vb6).

Your code would look something like:

```
Dim Cmd1 As ADODB.Command
Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
Cmd1.ActiveConnection = db
Cmd1.CommandText = "SP_SumOfTransComm"
Cmd1.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter(, adVarWChar, , 255, prodcode)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter(, adVarWChar, , 255, orderNum)
Dim TransRs As ADODB.Recordset
Set TransRs = Cmd1.Execute()
```

Comment: This appears *almost* right, but calling Execute on a Command object always returns a read-only, forward-only cursor.  I believe that you need to create a new Recordset object and call Open on it passing the Command object as the Source parameter (with no Connection parameter since you already set ActiveConnection).  This allows you to request specific locking and cursor types.

Comment: Thx. I will try this, because using Execute was not working. I'm guessing it would be  `TransRS.Open Cmd1, db`

Comment: For some reason, when doing Append, it is adding more {?} to the Stored Procedure, and instead of 2 parameters, it has 4 now. So I'm solving it with a direct text command as seen on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters should be enclosed in quotes and separated by commas e.g.

```
transcommQuery = "EXECUTE SP_SumOfTransComm '@prodcode', '@orderNum';"
transcommQuery = Replace$(transcommQuery, "@prodcode", prodcode)
transcommQuery = Replace$(transcommQuery, "@orderNum", orderNum)
```

...but then you have to worry about escaping quotes and other such nasties.

Better to use a `Command` object with strongly-typed `Parameter` objects and let the OLE DB provider handle sanitizing values. See @MicSim's answer for some example code.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me now, doing the following:

```
Set TransRs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim transcommQuery As String

transcommQuery = "{ call SP_SumOfTransComm('" & prodcode & "','" & orderNum & "') }"

TransRs.Open transcommQuery, db, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
```